# Can't install OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.1 on OS X

Tags: opengl, haskell, cabal

When I run

```
$ cabal install OpenGLRaw
```

I get the following errors.

```
... ... ...

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:78:20:
     error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:79:19:
     error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c: In function ‘hs_OpenGLRaw_getProcAddress’:

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:97:0:
     error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:97:0:
     error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:97:0:  error: for each function it appears in.)

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:104:0:
     warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dlopen’

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:104:0:
     error: ‘RTLD_LAZY’ undeclared (first use in this function)

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:104:0:
     warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:115:0:
     warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dlsym’

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:115:0:
     warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

cbits/HsOpenGLRaw.c:126:0:
     warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I just installed the latest Haskell Platform for OS X and ran `cabal update` for good measure.

Comment: Yes, XCode 4, and I have no trouble building things from source, or installing packages via MacPorts. However, this probably is the only cabal package I've tried to install that contains native code.

Comment: iirc, GHC versions prior to 7.0.3 have issues with XCode 4 - what GHC are you using?

Comment: Hmm...I have OSX 10.5 and some version of XCode 3.  To date I've never seen these errors installing OpenGLRaw.  Not finding stdlib.h is especially suspicious.

Comment: @TomMD 7.0.2. How do I update GHC?

Comment: 7.0.2 isn't compatible with XCode 4. The 7.0.3 release fixes some bugs (as does using GHC 6.12.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like [ticket #5011](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5011) - XCode 4 on Mac + GHC 7.0.2 fails to link.

This is fixed in GHC 7.0.3 which will be part of the mid-April release of the Haskell Platform.

And alternative fix is to downgrade  to the 2010.2 Haskell Platform.

Comment: In case anyone has the same problem: this is correct, and I was able to download the .pkg installer of GHC 7.0.3 and everything works now.