# Problems installing Haskell library regex-pcre on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, installation, pcre

I'm trying to install the Haskell [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre) library using:

```
cabal install --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/include \
              --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include regex-pcre
```

However I get this weird error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring regex-pcre-0.94.2...
Preprocessing library regex-pcre-0.94.2...
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include/HsFFI.h:68,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/template-hsc.h:4,
                 from dist/build/Text/Regex/PCRE/Wrap_hsc_make.c:1:
/usr/include/float.h:8:24: error: float.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/template-hsc.h:9,
                 from dist/build/Text/Regex/PCRE/Wrap_hsc_make.c:1:
/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
compiling dist/build/Text/Regex/PCRE/Wrap_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /usr/bin/gcc -c dist/build/Text/Regex/PCRE/Wrap_hsc_make.c -o dist/build/Text/Regex/PCRE/Wrap_hsc_make.o -march=i686 -m32 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fno-stack-protector -march=i686 -m32 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -fno-stack-protector -march=i686 -m32 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=700 -Ddarwin_BUILD_OS -Ddarwin_HOST_OS -Di386_BUILD_ARCH -Di386_HOST_ARCH -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_PCRE_H -DSPLIT_BASE=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/bytestring-0.9.1.10/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/base-4.3.1.0/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include/
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
regex-pcre-0.94.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The gist of it, seems to be that it can't find a second `float.h` file:

```
/usr/include/float.h:8:24: error: float.h: No such file or directory
```

I've opened /usr/include/float.h and line 8 reads:

```
#include_next <float.h>
```

I've done my searching on Google, and although I don't know that much C I think I understand what that line is supposed to say, but... I don't know how to really solve this problem. I don't know where else I have a `float.h` file on my system.

The GHC and GCC versions I'm using. GCC comes from XCode 4. GHC is 32bit, but I've tried the 64bit version too, with the same results.

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.2
```

OS X version is 10.6.7.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like [ticket #5011](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5011) - XCode 4 on Mac + GHC 7.0.2 fails to link.

This is fixed in GHC 7.0.3 which will be part of the mid-April release of the Haskell Platform.

And alternative fix is to downgrade to the 2010.2 Haskell Platform.

See this question yesterday: [Can't install OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.1 on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626339/cant-install-openglraw-1-1-0-1-on-os-x)

Comment: Downgrading to the 2010.2 Haskell Platform fixes the problem indeed. I'll use it until the next release of the platform. Thanks!